# itext7 Java A specific character SurrogatePair-string is not displayed

Tags: java, itext7

I am using the iText7 7.1.1 to create tables with SurrogatePair-string.
It is not displayed when the first SurrogatePair-character is "U+2000B".
In the case of the second and subsequent characters, it is displayed.
Environment: java version "1.7.0_45".

```
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Table;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFont;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.io.font.PdfEncodings;
import java.io.File;

public class SimpleTable {
    public static final String DEST = "SimpleTable.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File(DEST);
        new SimpleTable().manipulatePdf(DEST);
    }

    protected void manipulatePdf(String dest) throws Exception {
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
        Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);

        // UTF-8 encoding table and Unicode characters
        // http://www.utf8-chartable.com/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=131072&unicodeinhtml=hex&htmlent=1
        byte[] bUtf16A = {(byte)0xd8, (byte)0x40, (byte)0xdc, (byte)0x0b}; // First-String  U+2000B
        byte[] bUtf16B = {(byte)0xd8, (byte)0x69, (byte)0xde, (byte)0xb2}; // Second-String U+2A6B2

        String strUtf16A = new String(bUtf16A, "UTF-16");
        String strUtf16B = new String(bUtf16B, "UTF-16");
        String strUtf16AB = strUtf16A + strUtf16B;
        String strUtf16BA = strUtf16B + strUtf16A;
        //PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont("C:/Windows/Fonts/msmincho.ttc,0", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);
        PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont("C:/Windows/Fonts/meiryo.ttc,0", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);

        Table table = new Table(4);
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            if (i < 4) {
                table.addCell(new Paragraph(strUtf16A).setFont(font).setFontSize(12)); // Not Display String
            } else if (i < 8) {
                table.addCell(new Paragraph(strUtf16B).setFont(font).setFontSize(12)); // Display String
            } else if (i < 12) {
                table.addCell(new Paragraph(strUtf16AB).setFont(font).setFontSize(12)); // Not Display First-String
            } else {
                table.addCell(new Paragraph(strUtf16BA).setFont(font).setFontSize(12)); // Display Strings
            }
        }
        doc.add(table);
        doc.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clearly a bug in iText. It has been logged into internal bug-tracking system and will be handled in one of the next versions.

This character is being incorrectly trimmed, that's why it is missing in the resultant PDF.

Meanwhile, as a workaround you can prepend a zero-width joiner character (`U200d`) to the start of the string. This will solve the problem, but please bear in mind that it's a workaround and it might not work in the future versions of iText.

This line works:

```
table.addCell(new Paragraph("\u200d" + strUtf16A).setFont(font).setFontSize(12));
```

**UPD** The bug is fixed in iText 7.1.2 version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this issue is a bug. I will respond by inserting a blank at the beginning.